# Facebook post a <div> in users wall

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

Is there any way of posting a whole div into a users Facebook wall through my Facebook Application?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. You can only include basic HTML markup (such as `<b>`) and you can attach pictures or videos. But an entire div or additional CSS is not possible as it would allow anyone to mess with Facebook's markup.

Comment: Basically, i would like to post to user's wall an image and at the top of this image to have users name. Maybe this explains more what i'm asking.

Comment: You could post an image which has the user's name in it. That means you have to generate this image yourself and post that. But it's not possible to post HTML/CSS on a wall.

Comment: So, you advise to implement this by outputting this image with the name on it with php?
Something like generating a screenshot with php?

Comment: Yes, if you really want it then I think this is the only approach.

Comment: Can you please provide me the best approach of doing this or a link from Stack Overflow? Many thanks!